# I am using Jmeter to run api squentially. I want to find the number of apis taking less than 10ms, 20ms, 30ms etc. Can It be done from Jmeter?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmx

TotalAPi = 50 | Thread= 2 | Transaction= 50*2 = 100

> 10ms = 75 | >20ms = 20 | >30ms =  5

Answer (score 0):

If you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/result.jtl
```

the [result.jtl](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) file would be a normal [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file which can be opened in [Excel](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiWteGop5b6AhVMtaQKHf9vDGUQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-ww%2Fmicrosoft-365%2Fexcel&usg=AOvVaw3RJKdC8CC0nDgoyJdQOl1u) or equivalent and you can calculate the sum of samplers basing on their elapsed time, take a look at i.e. [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) function

[image]